# Only first of two identical if statements is executed in bash

Tags: bash

I have a small `bash` test script like this:

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep --silent "$1" "$3"; then echo "$1 not matched."; fi; exit 1;
if ! grep --silent "$2" "$3"; then echo "$2 not matched."; fi; exit 1;
```

and a test file like this:

```
$ cat foobar
FOO
BAR
```

Now I do the following:

```
$ ./test FOO BAR foobar
$ ./test FOOH BAR foobar
FOOH not matched.
$ ./test FOO BARG foobar
$
```

In my mind the last run, `./test FOO BARG foobar` should produce the output `BARG not matched.` and the script stop executing. What's the reason this does not work as I expect it to? Is there a better way of achieving the same logic?

**Edit:**

Also, if I comment out the second statement, like this:

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash
#if ! grep --silent "$1" "$3"; then echo "$1 not matched."; fi; exit 1;
if ! grep --silent "$2" "$3"; then echo "$2 not matched."; fi; exit 1;
```

The second if statement is executed:

```
$ ./test FOO BARG
$ BARG not matched.
```

So it seems that only the first of the consecutive if statements are executed. This also happens if I extend the script to have three similar if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like this with bit better formatting:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep --silent "$1" "$3"; then
  echo "$1 not matched.";
fi;

exit 1;

if ! grep --silent "$2" "$3"; then
  echo "$2 not matched.";
fi;

exit 1;
```

Probably you wanted to have the exit statements within the ifs:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep --silent "$1" "$3"; then
  echo "$1 not matched.";
  exit 1;
fi;

if ! grep --silent "$2" "$3"; then
  echo "$2 not matched.";
  exit 1;
fi;
```